# Fine Uploader - limiting total number of uploadable images

Tags: fine-uploader

I'm trying to find out if the Fine Uploader can limit the total amount of images allowed. So lets say I'd like to limit the images to 5 and a user drag and drops or selects 6 images it will prompt the user saying that can't be done due to only allowing a maximum of 5 images.

I've been looking at the documentation but I might have missed it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the `validation.itemLimit` option to match the max number of files you want to add, change the `validation.acceptFiles` and `validation.allowedExtensions` to match only image files ([validation docs](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/validation.html))

```js
var uploader = new qq.FineUploader({
    /* ... */
    validation: {
         itemLimit: 5,
         acceptFiles: 'image/*',
         allowedExtensions: ['.jpe', '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.gif', '.png', '.bmp', '.ico', '.svg', '.svgz', '.tif', '.tiff', '.ai', '.drw', '.pct', '.psp', '.xcf', '.psd', '.raw']
    }
});
```

**Note:** If you want a custom error message, then change text of the `messages.tooManyItemsError` option to equal the specific error message you want ([error handling docs](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/handling-errors.html)).
You can also add code to the onError callback to customize how and when your message is shown ([events docs](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/events.html)) or do some other operation.

Comment: I believe the extensions are to be listed without the dot. Like `['jpg','png','gif']`. See [this demo](https://fineuploader.com/demos.html).